# PHP scraping with DOM and multiprocess fopen() function, returns error ( Call to a function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object) in analyzing html

Tags: php, web-scraping, multiprocessing

I'll try to be little more clear in my text than in title.

I've build a php page that scrape another internet site and store results in array, than in database (the is repeated for 155 times and these multiple calls are based on another array).

In order to obtain faster result I've implemented another php page that using fopen() call "scraping page" multiple times (about 5 five times) dividing the original array in 5 parts.

Everything works everytime I call the scraping page iterating for the 155 times, one by one. But when I use fopen() it starts returning me (sometimes) this error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object
```

So I guess it should be a metter of "multiprocessing" so If I activate scrape too many time togheter, it returns me error.

So I've tried to call "scraping page" 3 or 2 times togheter than giving a rest to the script (sleep(1)) and than call other 2/3 times the scraping page.
In this case too, sometime I obtain all the script working perfectly, other time I have always the same error again.

This is part of my code.
FROM SCRAPING PAGE (scrape script):

```
function taxExtract($countryList,$urlTax,$countryID,$countryName,$countryTag) {

 echo $urlTax;

 $optionsTax = Array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,  // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,  // Setting cURL to follow 'location' HTTP headers
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE, // Automatically set the referer where following 'location' HTTP headers
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 300,   // Setting the amount of time (in seconds) before the request times out
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 300,  // Setting the maximum amount of time for cURL to execute queries
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, // Setting the maximum number of redirections to follow
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8",  // Setting the useragent
            CURLOPT_URL => $urlTax, // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function
 );

 $TaxCurl = curl_init($urlTax);
 curl_setopt_array($TaxCurl, $optionsTax);   // Setting cURL's options using the previously assigned array data in $options
 $resultTaxCurl = curl_exec($TaxCurl);
 $htmlTax = $resultTaxCurl;

 $domTax = new DOMDocument();
 $htmlTax = $domTax->loadHTML($htmlTax);

 $domTax->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

 $taxFullArr = array();
                    $taxFullArr[] = array (
                    'countryID' => $countryID,
                    'countryName' => $countryName,
                    'countryTag' => $countryTag);

 $alltaxtables = $domTax->getElementsByTagName('table');

 if($alltaxtables->length > 1) { // GET ONLY THE FIRST TABLE IF THERE ARE MORE THAN 1
    $taxtable = $alltaxtables->item(2);
 }

        $taxrows = $taxtable->getElementsByTagName("tr");
            foreach($taxrows as $taxrow) {
                $taxcols = $taxrow->getElementsByTagName('td'); 
                if (($taxcols->item(0)->nodeValue != "Resource") and ($taxcols->item(1)->nodeValue != "VAT") and ($taxcols->item(2)->nodeValue != "Import Tax") and ($taxcols->item(3)->nodeValue != "Income Tax")) {
                    echo "this is Country ID: ".$countryID." - ";
                    echo "this is Country Name: ".$countryName." - ";
                    echo "this is Country Tag: ".$countryTag." - ";
                    echo "this is Resource: ".$taxRes = $taxcols->item(0)->nodeValue." - "; 
                    echo "this is Vat tax: ".trim($taxIva = $taxcols->item(1)->nodeValue)." - "; 
                    echo "this is Import tax: ".trim($taxImport = $taxcols->item(2)->nodeValue)." - "; 
                    echo "this is Work tax: ".trim($taxWork =  $taxcols->item(3)->nodeValue)." - "; 

                $taxList[] = array (
                    'taxRes' => $taxRes,
                    'taxVat' => $taxIva,
                    'taxImport' => $taxImport,
                    'taxIncome' => $taxWork
                );

            }}
    $taxFullArr[] = $taxList;
 };
```

**ERROR IS ALWAYS RELATED TO THIS PART OF THE CODE:**

```
 $taxrows = $taxtable->getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

**FROM MULTY PROCESS PAGE (multiprocess script):**

```
 if (($totC > 150) && ($totC <= 200)) {
    echo "<br>do something it's between 151-200";

    //> 150 - 5 array
    $part1 = array();
    $part2 = array();
    $part3 = array();
    $part4 = array();
    $part5 = array();

    list($part1, $part2, $part3, $part4, $part5) = array_chunk($countryList, ceil(count($countryList) / 5));

    echo "<br><br>ARRAY 1: <br>";
    print_r($part1);
    echo "<br>total count for part1 = ".count($part1);
    $data1 = extractTax($server,$part1); sleep(1);
    echo "<br><br>ARRAY 2: <br>";
    print_r($part2);
    echo "<br>total count for part2 = ".count($part2);
    $data2 = extractTax($server,$part2); sleep(1);  

    resp($data1);
    echo_flush();
    resp($data2);
    echo_flush();       

    echo "<br><br>ARRAY 3: <br>";
    print_r($part3);
    echo "<br>total count for part3 = ".count($part3);
    $data3 = extractTax($server,$part3); sleep(1);
    echo "<br><br>ARRAY 4: <br>";
    print_r($part4);
    echo "<br>total count for part4 = ".count($part4);
    $data4 = extractTax($server,$part4); sleep(1);

    resp($data3);       
    echo_flush();
    resp($data4);       
    echo_flush();       

    echo "<br><br>ARRAY 5: <br>";
    print_r($part5);
    echo "<br>total count for part5 = ".count($part5);
    $data5 = extractTax($server,$part5); sleep(1);

    resp($data5);       
    echo_flush(); 
}

function extractTax($server,$cList) { 
   echo "<br><br><i>***** Country List Updater ******</i></p><br>";
   echo "<i>***** Server $server *****</i><br>";  

   echo "<br><i><p class='start'>** Launched process $server **</i></p>";
   $cLists = base64_encode(serialize($cList));
   $url = "[...url...]/cData.php?server=".$server."&cList=".$cLists;
   $child = fopen($url, 'r');
   if ($child == TRUE) {
      echo "<br>Worked! Move on...<br>";
   } else {
      $i = 0;
      while ($child == FALSE && $i<=3) {
        echo "There's problem with fopen(), waiting for next try<br>";
        sleep(60); 
        $i++;
        echo "<br>Attempt $i/3 (after the 3rd, I'll move on)<br>";
        $child = fopen($url, 'r');
    }   
    if ($child == TRUE) {
        echo "<br>Finally worked! Moving on...<br>";
    }
    if ($child == FALSE && $i == 3) {
        echo "After 3 usuccessful attempts, I'm moving on...<br>";
    }
} return $child;    
};

function resp($data) {
   // get response from child (if any) as soon at it's ready:
   $response = stream_get_contents($data);
   echo "<br><b><p class='buytitles'>+++This is RESPONSE from process+++</b></p>";
   echo "<br>".$response;
   echo "<br><b><p class='buyendtitles'>---RESPONSE END process ---</b><br></p>";
 fclose($data);
 echo_flush();
 }
```

Do you know why does it happens? Do you know how could I correct it?

Pls ask for further explanation, sorry if I haven't been enough clear.
Alberto

Answer (score 0):

`if (!taxtable) throw new SomeException();`

Put your scraping logic in a function then `try` that function and check your errors that way.

Can't really help you scrape a webpage that I don't know the data on. Can you give example data from your curl request and a sample table?